# DownloadStringAsync() does not download the string asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, webclient, downloadstring

Trying to implement `downloadStringAsync()` to prevent UI freezing for 10 seconds when downloading *one byte* of data.  However, even though the download completes, it is freezing the UI just as if I used `downloadString()`.

Here is my code:

```
    public void loadHTML()
    {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();

            // Specify that the DownloadStringCallback2 method gets called
            // when the download completes.
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(loadHTMLCallback);
            client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.example.com"));
            return;
    }

    public void loadHTMLCallback(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // If the request was not canceled and did not throw
        // an exception, display the resource.
        if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
        {
            string result = (string)e.Result;

            // Do cool stuff with result

        }
    }
```

Comment: You're downloading *one byte of data* and noticing a significant delay, asynchronous or not? That is a huge problem in and of itself. Is that really all the code? If you're certain your internet connection doesn't work at a speed of 1 bps, I think you have other code there. Spawning a new thread to asynchronously download something should take about the same time as synchronously downloading one byte. It might also be that `DownloadStringAsync` synchronously checks headers, internet connectivity, or something before creating and executing the new thread, but that's a guess.

Comment: Added `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;` and everything works fine now! It appears that auto proxy detection was the reason for the delay.

Comment: Where's "the WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;"? I could not find the property called "DefaultWebProxy" for WebRequest Class, @Johnny.

Answer (score 2):

Encountered the same problem, and found a solution.
Quite complex discussion here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a00dba00-5432-450b-9904-9d343c11888d/webclient-downloadstringasync-freeze-my-ui?forum=ncl

In short, the problem is web client is searching for proxy servers and hanging the app.
The following solution helps:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Proxy = null;
... Do whatever else ...
```